# Flutter & Firestore location-based queries & data structure

Tags: firebase, flutter, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am currently working on an app that will connect clients and craftsmen. Right now I am structuring the database and thinking about possible queries. I noticed that it is not so easy to use the location-based aspect and I am right now struggling with this and my research didnt really help.
I am using Flutter & Firestore.

#### How I started to structure the data

```
{
    "jobs": {
        "jobid":{
            "title": "Repair my TV",
            "description": "some text here",
            "postal_code": 10827,
            "city": "Berlin, Germany"
        }
    }
}
```

Like this I could easily query by city. I have the feeling that this is not the optimal solution to the problem.

#### What I try to achieve

I would like to query it in some kind of radius, like:
A craftsman wants to see all available jobs in 10km radius.

Anybody got some tips to solve this problem?

Edit: I thought of using Geopoints but I read that Firestore cannot do a GeoQuery, is that right?

Comment: Could you include your code so there is more context to help?

Comment: I haven't really written code yet. Its more a theoretical question since its more about database structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of the data structure you would need to add the geolocation components

- Latitude
- Longitude

As this are the components that will be used for the geo queries once you are developing your app.

As you are using fluttter [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYHVyl-juUk) is a video for the whole process of using maps and geoqueries which can be useful for you once you start the implementation.